# Configure pinescript forex strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have done this for crypto and regular stocks, but in the US, there is no leverage with those. I think it is the leverage that is screwing me up.
I am looking to configure my forex strategy and cannot make heads or tales of it.
What comes after

```
//@version=5

strategy("nameOfStrategyGoesHere", overlay = true,
```

Details needed:
Original account size is $1000 USD.

Oanda is my broker, so I do not have to trade in defined lot sizes
I want to trade 2% of my account per trade

long and short leverage is 50:1

Only one open trade at a time should be allowed (my script will also not allow multiple open positions, but I think its good to set this too. I think it is pyramiding = 0, but not quite sure)

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, have a look at [strategy()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy), and maybe the whole concept of [Strategies](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html).